# How to disable creating .sbr and .bsc in Visual Studio C++ Project?

Tags: c++, visual-studio

I have Below Settings, but my project still creates .sbr and .bsc file.

[image]

What could be the reason?
How can I disable creating those files?

Comment: Check the  time stamps on your .sbr and .bsc files. They might turn out to be old files. Perhaps you are using the "Build solution" command rather than "Rebuild solution" after making this configuration change.

Comment: @RexGray No. All time stamps are fresh. Is there any other settings I need to check? I'm using vs2012

Comment: My advice may be useless then, because I am using vs2017. I found that I needed to use the "Rebuild Solution" command in order to cause removal of .sbr and .bsc files. Another option would be to manually delete those files and then see whether they are re-built. As far as I know, you have correctly made the only change that affects them.

Comment: What is your Visual Studio version? Note that behavior has changed since Visual Studio 2008: [an SQL Server .sdf file is used instead](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/87x7wc99.aspx).

Answer (score 2):

As there are several ways of enabling the feature, more awkward ones need to be checked also:

- *Enable Browse Information* may be set in **another** configuration

  - By default it's (was) only set in *Debug* but I've seen some projects setting in *Release* also
  - The *Configuration* selector is in the property pages, above the part in the (question's) screenshot
  - One may wish to run through available configurations (to find the potential guilty) and then use the *All Configurations* to set all at once
- *Additional Options* can be **appended** to the ones configurable in the GUI

  - Check *Configuration Properties*, *C/C++*, *Command Line*, *Additional Options* for [compiler options](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/cpp/build/reference/creating-an-dot-sbr-file) `/FR` or `/Fr`
- Your project may be creating the browse information in a **custom action**

  - Check *Build Events* for custom `cl` or [`bscmake`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/cpp/build/reference/building-a-dot-bsc-file) commands

Answer (score 2):

If you did all of [what Helder Magalhães wrote](https://stackoverflow.com/a/45509773/4457355) and VS **still** creates .sbr and .bsc files then you have to check *all* source files in the project, because they can have that setting for them individually (as I found out):

- Open each source file's Property Pages dialog box.
- Click the C/C++ folder.
- Click the Browse Information property page.
- Modify the Browse Information File
- or Disable Browse Information property.

Answer (score 1):

Today I learned my lesson on VS 
... each cpp file has his own properties in the project file. 
... and its possible to configure the project to no browseinformation and enable the option at file-level

Solution for my BSCMAKE error was to disable the option in the project (already done) AND to set the option for each cpp file in the project to "no" .. could be done manually or with search and replace in the vcxproj file.

Answer (score 0):

I'll post this solution here even though this post is old, as it's not mentioned in the post.

I found that once you enable the .bsc file generation, it's on forever.  Even setting it to false doesn't stop its generation.  If you have the following line in your .vcxproj file:

```
<BrowseInformation>false</BrowseInformation>
```

Then the file is still generated!  The only way to stop it is to manually edit your .vcxproj file and delete this line (which is quite safe to do).

It worked for me;  perhaps someone else Googling this problem will find this helpful.